# Unique consecutive values from SQL Server Audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our database contains an audit table which gets a new row added every time a projects fee value is changed. Unfortunately it can also get rows added when there is not actually a change from the prior values. I have been tasked with extracting this data so we can see how a projects value has changed over time however I would like to exclude any consecutive duplicate rows from the output. Duplicate values that are non-consecutive are perfectly fine as they reflect a project going up and down in value

Simplified Example Data

```
ID 1, DateCreated 2016-03-02, Value 0
ID 2, DateCreated 2016-03-04, Value 0
ID 3, DateCreated 2016-03-05, Value 20
ID 4, DateCreated 2016-03-06, Value 50
ID 5, DateCreated 2016-03-07, Value 50
ID 6, DateCreated 2016-03-08, Value 20
ID 7, DateCreated 2016-03-10, Value 20
ID 8, DateCreated 2016-03-11, Value 0
```

Based on this data, I would expect to see the following result

```
ID 1, DateCreated 2016-03-02, Value 0
ID 3, DateCreated 2016-03-05, Value 20
ID 4, DateCreated 2016-03-06, Value 50
ID 6, DateCreated 2016-03-08, Value 20
ID 8, DateCreated 2016-03-11, Value 0
```

I have tried using the Row_Number Partition feature though this is grouping together rows that are not consecutive

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(SELECT id, 
DateCreated, 
Value
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY id) AS rn
FROM tblTest) AS Test
WHERE Test.rn = 1

ID 1, DateCreated 2016-03-02, Value 0
ID 3, DateCreated 2016-03-05, Value 20
ID 4, DateCreated 2016-03-06, Value 50
```

I therefore wonder if anyone has any advice as to how I may do this? The SQL version I am using is 2008R2 Express however it would not be a showstopper to upgrade to a newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the difference of row numbers approach to classify consecutive values into groups. Then get the first row in each group using the `row_number` function.

Run the innermost query to see how group values are assigned based on consecutive values (ordered by datecreated) being the same.

```
select id,datecreated,value 
from (select *,row_number() over(partition by grp order by datecreated) as rn
      from (select *
            ,row_number() over(order by datecreated) 
            - row_number() over(partition by value order by datecreated) as grp
            from t
           ) x
      ) y
where rn = 1
```

In versions 2012 and beyond, you can use the [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) function to get the first value in each group.

```
select distinct 
 first_value(id) over(partition by grp order by datecreated) as id
,first_value(datecreated) over(partition by grp order by datecreated) as datecreated
,value
from (select *
      ,row_number() over(order by datecreated) 
      - row_number() over(partition by value order by datecreated) as grp
      from t) x
```

Comment: Many thanks, this seems to be perfect! - the First_Value function sounds pretty good too and I will do some looking up on it.I will get this answer upvoted when I get enough rep points to do so

Answer (score 0):

Add the ORDER BY to your inner-query, and to a lesser extent, your outer query. Make it look like this...

```
SELECT  *
FROM
    (SELECT id, 
        DateCreated, 
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM tblTest
    ORDER BY id) AS Test
WHERE Test.rn = 1
ORDER BY Test.id
```

That should return you results you're looking for.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, I did consider an approach like this however you cannot use an Order By clause in a subquery